# Functions on products of tori

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

Let $T$ be an algebraic torus over an algebraically closed field $k$.
Let $d\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$. For every $d$-tuple of integers $\underline{n}=(n_1,\dotsc, n_d)$ and a function $f\in k[T]$, we can consider the functions $f_{\underline{n}}$ on $T^{d}$ given by:

$$(t_1,\dotsc, t_d)\mapsto f(t_1^{n_{1}}\dotsm t_{d}^{n_{d}}).$$

Do these functions generate $k[T^{d}]$?

Comment: Yes.  This is [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6), Proposition 8.4.

Comment: this proposition says that a diagonalizable group is isomorphic to a subgroup of diagonal matrices. I already know it is a torus, how it is relevant?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445275/functions-on-products-of-tori#comment1150122_445275), it also says that a subgroup of diagonal matrices, like yours, is diagonalisable.  The definition of diagonalisability (see the beginning of Section 8.2) is that the character lattice spans the ring of regular functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more precisely, $k[T^d]$ is the group algebra on $\mathbb{Z}^d$. See Milne, Algebraic Groups, 12.3.